# why does start debugging a spring boot application in intellij start 2 process and not one?

Tags: java, spring-boot, debugging, intellij-idea

I have a simple spring boot application. when I use Intellij to debug the application using the main class it starts 2 different processes. Here are the screenshots of the steps I am doing:

1. [starting application main class in debug mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AfwIr.png)
2. [it opens 2 debug windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WLR0N.png)
3. [also I can see two processes started](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pAOmo.png)

I was expecting that when I start the application in debug mode it should start one process and I should be able to see the logs in that process. As of now, my debug pointers are applicable in the second process while my logs statements are visible in the console of the first process. Anyone can suggest why this is in this specific way?

Comment: There is related issue on YouTrack: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-200694

Comment: Thanks a ton, @y.bedrov. It solved the problem.